# Запятая перед союзом "как" во фразе "Изучение человека как субъекта социальной среды"

Tags: пунктуация, как

Если ставится запятая, то под какой из 3-х случаев правила она подпадает (это же, вроде, не сравнительный оборот)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, так как в данном случае "как" означает "в качестве", а не сравнение.

Comment: Правильно, но тут любят более подробные ответы со ссылками. Есть же еще много случаев, когда запятая перед "как" нужна. Не только сравнение. И случаев, когда не нужна - тоже...